# PHP Array Post Method

Tags: php, arrays, post

When I am trying to POST an Array Having some ploblems,

Here is my code

Thanks in advance

```
for(;$i>0;$i=$i-1){
    $j=$new+1;
    echo '</br>'.$j.'. <form action="3.php" method="post"/><input type="textarea" name="o[.$new]"/><input type="text" name="o2[.$new]"/><input type="text" name="o3[.$new]"/><input type="submit" value="Send"/></form></br>';
    $new=$new+1;
}
```

What I am trying to achive is to create dynamic number of textarea, and wait user to fill up these area, then post these datas to the "3.php" page.

```
<form action="3.php" method="post"/>
    <input type="textarea" name="o[.$new]"/>
    <input type="text" name="o2[.$new]"/>
    <input type="text" name="o3[.$new]"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Variables are not parsed inside single quoted strings. Use `"`

Comment: Thank you. However, that's not the main problem, The problem I have is to POST dynamic number of variables

I need to take a number from a user, then create this number of textarea, wait user to fill those areas, then print the datas.

Comment: And what is the main problem? I don't see anything in a question related to the problem.

Comment: The problem I have is to POST dynamic number of variables I need to take a number from a user, then create this number of textarea, wait user to fill those areas, then print the datas

Comment: And you can't do **what**?

Comment: You can't do that in the same form. First, you have to built a form for posting the number of the textareas you want, and then do the `for` statement to `echo` them.

Comment: I cannot do that, Can you please write me a piece of code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First form for posting the number of the textareas:

```
<form action="posting.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="textareasNum">
    <input type="submit" value="Send the number of textareas">
</form>
```

The posting.php is:

```
<form action="3.php" method="post">
    <?php
        $num = $_POST['textareasNum'];
        for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
           {
    ?>
             <textarea name="o<?php echo $i;?>">
             </textarea>
    <?php
           }
    ?>
</form>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for this, It works fine! :)

Last question:)

How can I code to gather entered values in textareas ?
I couldn't create a valiable name like o2 or o8 dynamically

Comment: Sure you can, like this: `for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++){ $data_array[] = $_POST['o'.$i];}`. Now, you have all the values you want in `$data_array[]`.

Comment: Previous code is for `3.php` file. You can send the `$num` value using this: `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $num;?>" />` after `<form>` tag.